# Is there an biblatex equivalent to natbib's citealp command?

Tags: biblatex

Currently I'm trying out biblatex but not entirely committed, so I've declared a few aliases in my preamble (which I can comment out if I compile in bibtex):

```
\newcommand{\citep}{\autocite}
\newcommand{\citet}{\textcite}
\newcommand{\citealp}{\cite}
```

(I read in another thread that `\autocite` is better than `\parencite` to use in place of `\citep`.)

However, `\cite` does not add the comma between author(s) and year that `\citealp` does. Do I have to declare my own command for this or is there another equivalent? I've looked in the biblatex manual (which seems to one of the few comprehensive references at the moment) but have not been able to find the answer to this.

Also, following up with a more subjective question, how close to mainstream is biblatex in the LaTeX community? I find information outside of †he manual very scarce; there is not even a Wikipedia page for biblatex...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To simulate `natbib` in BibLaTeX you can use the `natbib` option, e.g., `\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}`, and there is no need to redefine the standard `natbib` citation commands.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the natbib solution didn't work for me.

However this worked: \usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,…]{biblatex}
(adapted from @Åsmund)