# Write complex citations with BibLatex - "&" needed instead of "and"

Tags: biblatex, apa6

Using `BibLatex` with the `apa` style I try to cite some references in the following way:

> ... slightly adapted Biggs’ (1987, 1999; see for a similar model Marsick, Watkins, & O’Conner, 2011) model of ...

I tried to get the result as following (MWE)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{biggs1987,
    location = {Melbourne},
    title = {Student approaches to learning and studying},
    publisher = {Australian Council for Educational Research},
    author = {Biggs, J.},
    date = {1987}
}

@book{biggs1999,
    location = {Buckingham},
    title = {Teaching for quality learning at university. What the student does},
    publisher = {Society for Research into Higher Education},
    author = {Biggs, J.},
    date = {1999}
}

@incollection{marsick2011,
    location = {London},
    title = {Researching workplace learning in the United States},
    pages = {198--209},
    booktitle = {The international handbook of workplace learning},
    publisher = {Sage},
    author = {Marsick, Victoria and Watkins, Karen and O'Conner, Bridget N.},
    editor = {Malloch, M. and Cairns, L. and Evans, K. and O'Conner, Bridget N.},
    date = {2011}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\ldots slightly adapted Biggs' (\citeyear{biggs1987, biggs1999}; see for a similar model \citeauthor{marsick2011}, \citeyear{marsick2011}) model of  \ldots

\end{document}
```

However, the output is only:

> ... slightly adapted Biggs’ (1987, 1999; see for a similar model Marsick, Watkins, and O’Conner, 2011) model of ...

As you see BibLatex prints an "**and**" instead of an "**&**". It seems as `\citeauthor` is only thought to be used as in-text citation (there the "**and**" is correct).

I guess I could make my life a little bit easier by using the `natbib` option (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88195/is-there-an-biblatex-equivalent-to-natbibs-citealp-command)). However, that changes some formations that I don't want to have changed.

**My question therefore is:** How do I get the ampersand (&) into the my citation without globally changing the **and** for in-text citations?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just go with `Biggs' (\citeyear{biggs1987, biggs1999}; see for a similar model \cite{marsick2011})`? You will get an "and" as well, but that is how the APA want it.

Comment: @moewe You are correct. I could use \cite{}. However, I do not think that the **and** is correct here. APA wants to have an ampersand within brackets. So the problem is still the same.

Comment: Aha, then add this monster before the `\cite` command: `\AtNextCite{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}>\maxprtauth}
      {}
      {\ifthenelse{\value{liststop}>2}
         {\finalandcomma\addspace\&\space}
         {\addspace\&\space}}}}`. (Modulo line breaks!)

Comment: @moewe Are you sure the "%" belongs in there? Without it seems to work. Thank you. However, this is a really ugly hack indeed. Anyway, if nobody comes up with a more elegant solution I'd like to accept your answer.

Comment: Well, that is why I said modulo line breaks, normally this kind of code is formatted with line breaks and then the `%` makes perfect sense (and is actually necessary). I will write up an answer so you can see the whole thing in its entire glory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to temporary influence `\finalnamedelim` here.

The obvious solution is to have

```
\AtNextCite{%
  \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnum\value{liststop}>2
       \finalandcomma
    \fi
    \addspace\&\space}}
```

before the offending citation.

Since this is quite long and looks odd in the document body you might want to define a new command for that.

```
\newcommand{\switchtoparencite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{%
      \ifnum\value{liststop}>2
        \finalandcomma
      \fi
      \addspace\&\space}}}
```

Then simply use `\switchtoparencite\cite{marsick2011}` and you are good to go.

You can of course also define a new citation command `\nparencite` that behaves as if it were a parenthetical citation, but misses the parentheses.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\nparencite}
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
```

You would then say `\nparencite{marsick2011}`

Which of the two solutions you prefer depends on the context, I guess; I for one think the second solution quite slick.

MWE (displaying both solutions)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber, sortcites=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{biggs1987,
    location = {Melbourne},
    title = {Student approaches to learning and studying},
    publisher = {Australian Council for Educational Research},
    author = {Biggs, J.},
    date = {1987}
}

@book{biggs1999,
    location = {Buckingham},
    title = {Teaching for quality learning at university. What the student does},
    publisher = {Society for Research into Higher Education},
    author = {Biggs, J.},
    date = {1999}
}

@incollection{marsick2011,
    location = {London},
    title = {Researching workplace learning in the United States},
    pages = {198--209},
    booktitle = {The international handbook of workplace learning},
    publisher = {Sage},
    author = {Marsick, Victoria and Watkins, Karen and O'Conner, Bridget N.},
    editor = {Malloch, M. and Cairns, L. and Evans, K. and O'Conner, Bridget N.},
    date = {2011}
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\switchtoparencite}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{%
      \ifnum\value{liststop}>2
        \finalandcomma
      \fi
      \addspace\&\space}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\nparencite}
  {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}

\begin{document}
\ldots slightly adapted Biggs' (\citeyear{biggs1987, biggs1999}; see for a similar model \switchtoparencite\cite{marsick2011}) model of \ldots

\citereset

\ldots slightly adapted Biggs' (\citeyear{biggs1987, biggs1999}; see for a similar model \nparencite{marsick2011}) model of \ldots

\end{document}
```

[image]